# Solving the integer programming problem using the Benders decomposition approach

Tags: python, cplex

I wanted to solve the simple example, given below, using the Benders decomposition approach.

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

# Creating model

    my_bdrex=Model('My Benders Model',log_output=True)
 
# Defining variables

    x_1=my_bdrex.integer_var(name='x_1', lb=0)

x_2=my_bdrex.integer_var(name='x_2', lb=0)

y_1=my_bdrex.integer_var(name='y_1', lb=0)

y_2=my_bdrex.integer_var(name='y_2', lb=0)

y_3=my_bdrex.integer_var(name='y_3', lb=0)

# Adding constraints
my_bdrex.add_constraint(2*x_1+4*x_2+4*y_1-2*y_2+3*y_3<=12)

my_bdrex.add_constraint(3*x_1+5*x_2+2*y_1+3*y_2-y_3<=10)

my_bdrex.add_constraint(x_1<=2)

my_bdrex.add_constraint(x_2<=2)

# Defining the objective function
objective_bdrex=4*x_1+7*x_2+2*y_1-3*y_2+y_3

# Solving the Model
my_bdrex.maximize(objective_bdrex)

my_bdrex.parameters.benders.strategy = 1

x_1.benders_annotation=0

x_2.benders_annotation=0

y_1.benders_annotation=1

y_2.benders_annotation=1

y_3.benders_annotation=1

my_bdrex_MP.print_information()

print(my_bdrex_MP.export_as_lp_string())

my_bdrex_MP.solve(clean_before_solve=True)

my_bdrex_MP.print_solution()
```

The above problem is an integer programming problem. I want to solve it by putting some variables in the master problem and remaining in the subproblem. But when I run the code I get the error: `CPLEX Error  2002: Invalid Benders decomposition`.

Comment: You appear to have incorrect indentation. Copy-paste error? Also, please provide the full stack trace, not just the error message.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

In documentation Benders decomposition: CPLEX default

> CPLEX implements a default Benders decomposition in certain
> situations.

We can read

> if there are no continuous variables in your model, CPLEX raises an
> error stating that it cannot automatically decompose the model to
> apply a Benders strategy.

There is no continuous variable in your model, which explains why you got an error